# How to cancel only a specific type job in MassTransit

Tags: .net, masstransit

Imagine multiple running MassTransit jobs of several types.
Knowing a job Id, a user can cancel any of the jobs even the ones he should not have access to. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

MassTransit is a framework, and job consumers are part of that framework. There isn't anything built into MassTransit that is going to manage authorization.

It is expected that your application, by allowing a `CancelJob` message to be produced, is going to ensure that it is safe/allowable to produce such a message.

Comment: The reason I expected MT to handle that is that it already knows everything about a job. I guess I could query MT job store to find a job type?